# Regex to match everything before two forward-slashes (//) not contained in quotes

Tags: regex

I've been grappling with some negative lookahead and lookbehind patterns to no avail. I need a regex that will match everything in a string before two forward slashes, unless said characters are in quotes.

For example, in the string `"//this is a string//" //A comment about a string about strings`,
the substring `"//this is a string//"` ought to be matched and the rest ignored.
As you can see, the point is to exclude any single-line comments (C++/Java style).
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
\/\/[^\"']*$
```

It will match `//` if it is not followed by either a `"` or a `'`. It's not exactly what you requested, but closely meets your requirements. It will only choke on comments that contain `"` or `'`, like

```
// I like "bread".
```

Maybe better than no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
^([^/"]|".+?"|/[^/"])*
```

Answer (score 0):

A python/regex based comment remover I wrote a while back, if it's helpful:

```
def remcomment(line):
  for match in re.finditer('"[^"]*"|(//)', line):
    if match.group(1):
      return line[:match.start()].rstrip()
  return line
```